# Adding RadTextBox inside RadPanelItem

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Is it possible to add RadTextBox inside RadPanelItem which is inside RadPanelBar? I'm not sure whether is it possible and if it is how to accomplish that using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Of Course :) you can add RadTextBox in RadPanelBar using `ItemTemplate`

```
 <telerik:RadPanelBar ID="RadPanelBar1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadPanelItem>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" Label="Textbox">
                </telerik:RadTextBox><br />
                       <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox2" runat="server" Label="Textbox2">
                </telerik:RadTextBox><br />
                       <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox3" runat="server" Label="Textbox3">
                </telerik:RadTextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadPanelItem>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadPanelBar>
```

This is javascript code to add new `RadPanelItem` ,

```
 function AddItem()
{
    var panel = $find("RadPanelBar1");

    if (_persist)
 {
        panel.trackChanges();
 }

    var childItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadPanelItem();

    childItem.set_text("NewItem");

    item.get_parent().get_items().add(childItem);

    if (_persist)
 {
         panel.commitChanges();
 }
}
```

Here , this code will add new `RadPanelItem` .
You can set your ItemTemplate of this item likes

```
childItem .ItemTemplate = .. your ItemTemplate using Itemplate ..
```

Comment: Can i do that using JavaScript?

Comment: Is there any reason for using Javascript ?

Comment: I'm making chat so i want when user click on person to add new RadPaneItem inside RadPanelBar which will have two RadTextBox's which will be used do display messages and for making new messages.